# How to display XML into a tree view?

Tags: .net, xml

I have a variable of XDocument, and I want to display its structure in a TreeView. I tried

`TreeView1.DataSource = doc;`

but I got this error

*HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx) as data source.

Comment: You mean use XmlDateSource instead of XDocument?

Comment: Create an XmlDataSource (you can find samples on MSDN) and bind it to your TreeView. XmlDataSource implements IHierarchicalDataSource.

Comment: I wish this option was there for the menu too.